# Unwanted Folds in Mesh when using Cycles

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I'm currently modeling an X-wing for an animation, but when I try to use Cycles for rendering it creates these folds. What am I supposed to do to fix it?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: maybe you need to Shade Smooth then Auto-Smooth, but could you please just share this part of the object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: if i do it looks wird, can u explain more please

Comment: You can change the Angle that Auto smooth operates at